# How to integrate Tomcat and Apache Apollo?

Tags: java, tomcat, activemq-classic, apollo

In my application, I have Apache Apollo messages sent from the client to the server, and vice versa, but Apollo server default Web server is Jetty, I can not find how to integrate Tomcat and Apache Apollo.

I have found info about integrating Tomcat with ActiveMQ here: http://activemq.apache.org/tomcat.html

Apollo compared to ActiveMQ updated source code and Scala architecture and I want to know how to integrate Tomcat with Apache Apollo.

Comment: Plz, fix syntax of your question after 'now only...', else it is a long sentence difficult to make sense.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very skilled, please you read it now

Comment: Although I do not know the answer to your question, I tried to improve your syntax. Hope it will help you getting an answer.

Comment: Can you not just run the broker by itself? Do you want to run it inside Tomcat? Or do you want to connect to a running broker from a deployed war?